# Help on correct Syntax for a MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I really could not understand what I am missing then I thought it would nice to ask you guys.
Here is my code sample.

```
    foreach ($disArray as $a) {

        $query = "SELECT num FROM ".$tableName." WHERE question='" . $a."'";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $this->conn) or die('Error: '.mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        //$row['num'] = $row['num'] + 1;

        $numb = $row['sayi'] + 1;

        $query = "UPDATE ".$tablename." SET `num`=" . $numb . "WHERE `question`=" . $a . "\"";
        mysql_query($query, $this->conn);
    }
```

Here `disArray` is an array :) And I am looping through it and it stores "senteces" in it. What I am trying to do is comparing those sentence with the ones in the table but I guess I have an error in my this `$query = "SELECT num FROM ".$username." WHERE question='" . $a."'";` query, as it gives and error like this;

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE question='Where are you from?'' at line 1
```

Also I was getting an error that says mysql_fetch_array requires resource but you are giving booling etc. But I do not know what it stops giving that error as well. What do you think guys? What would be the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, basic debugging: what is the value of `$username`?/`$tableName`? What is the value of `$query` after you create it?

Answer (score 0):

instead of $username you should provide database tablename to check

```
$query = "SELECT num FROM  '".$username."' WHERE question='" . $a."'";
```

Comment: Sorry but actually tablename is same as the $username. The mistake should be something else?

Comment: @Jay: The table name is the username? Do you have a table per user? If so, that's _horribly_ broken.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently problem is in your username variable, check if the value is correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend add quote as shown below!

$query = "UPDATE ".$tablename." SET `num`=" . $numb . "WHERE `question`='" . $a . "'"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$query = "SELECT num FROM ".$tableName." WHERE question='" . $a."'";
```

**Use this:**

```
$query = ' SELECT `num` FROM `'.$tableName.'` WHERE `question` = "'.$a.'" ';
```